# Can this be simplified in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-5.0, code-duplication

I have some duplicated code, but not sure of the best way to simplify it.

```
private void CheckData(long PKID, int ExpectedResult, string Server)
{
    var a = _ARepo.GetAll();
    var b = _BRepo.GetAll();

    if(Server == "A")
    {
        a.Find(x => x.PKID == PKID).Result.ShouldBe(ExpectedResultId);
    }

    if (Server == "B")
    {
        b.Find(x => x.PKID == PKID).Result.ShouldBe(ExpectedResultId);
    }
}
```

This is a unit test project and I'm using the `Shouldly` library. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: What are the types of `a` and `b`?

Comment: (Server == "A" ? a : b).Find(...) I suppose. Or just introduce one variable and assign either a or b to it, depending on Server. Then query Find on this variable.

Comment: @GiladGreen They are the same type using the Repository pattern with `Dapper` getting data from a SQL Server database.

Comment: @MarkAllison - what happens if it isn't "A" nor "B"?

Comment: Would you not be better just getting the data from Repo A or Repo B before you do any check?  You only need to get one lot of data here.

Comment: instead of saving lines of code, improve performance by only hitting one repository instead of two.

Comment: @Jonesopolis Why "instead", when you can do both at the same time?

Comment: @Jonesopolis Assuming they defer execution, his code would already be doing that.

Comment: @Jonesopolis the data is on two separate servers so I need two repos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private void CheckData(long PKID, int ExpectedResult, string Server)
{
    //Setting to empty because I don't know what happens if it is not "A" nor "B"
    IEnumerable<YourType> data = Enumerable.Empty<YourType>();

    if(Server == "A")
        data = _ARepo.GetAll();
    else if(Server == "B")
        data = _BRepo.GetAll();

    data.Find(Find(x => x.PKID == PKID).Result.ShouldBe(expectedId);
}
```

If the `Server` value can be only `A` or `B` then you can replace with an `if else` or better still a `?:` operator
Then it will look like:

```
var data = Server == "A" ? _ARepo.GetAll() : _BRepo.GetAll();
data.Find(Find(x => x.PKID == PKID).Result.ShouldBe(expectedId);
```

---

In the case that both `Repo`s implement the same interface a better design will be to get the `IRepo` as a parameter of the function. That way the function has only 1 role - which is to check data (and not also to decide which data to check)

Comment: Very helpful, I changed the method as per your suggestion to `private void CheckData(long PKID, int ExpectedResult, Repository repo)`

Comment: @MarkAllison - Glad to help :) BTW - if already writting UT and better responsibilities of code segments then I'd recommend to have a `IRepository` instead of a concrete `Repository` :)  Check out [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) - It is kind of the difference between writing code to making art :)

Answer (score 3):

You can make a helper method to deal with this duplication:

```
private void CheckFind<T>(List<T> a, int expectedId) where T : IWithId {
    a.Find(x => x.PKID == PKID).Result.ShouldBe(expectedId);
}
```

Call this method twice from `CheckData`:

```
if(Server == "A") {
    CheckFind(_ARepo.GetAll(), ExpectedResultId);
}
if(Server == "B") {
    CheckFind(_BRepo.GetAll(), ExpectedResultId);
}
```

Comment: @Evk True. However, assigning a single variable requires both types to be the same, while my approach can be easily adjusted to lists of generic type, with an interface for getting an ID.

Comment: @Servy This would be true if you could use `IEnumerable<T>`. However, use of `Find` suggests that OP uses `List<T>`, so no, your trick wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

yes if you can make code refactor your code and your `_ARepo.GeAll` and `_BRepo.getAll` implements the same interface in the  returned type  this will  be something like the following

```
private void CheckData(long PKID, int ExpectedResult, string Server, IRepo repo)
{
    var b = repo.GetAll();  
    b.Find(x => x.PKID == PKID).Result.ShouldBe(ExpectedResultId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using some short if notation you can use the following 
Assuming the following that _ARepo and _BRepo is the same from the same class but different connection strings

```
private void CheckData(long PKID, int ExpectedResult, string Server)
{
   BaseType repo = Server == "A" ? _ARepo : _BRepo;
   repo.GetAll().Find(x => x.PKID == PKID).Result.ShouldBe(ExpectedResultId);
}
```

Assuming that they are not the same BaseType but that GetAll() is IEnumerable

```
private void CheckData(long PKID, int ExpectedResult, string Server)
{
   IEnumerable<YourType> repo = Server == "A" ? _ARepo.GetAll() : _BRepo.GetAll();
   repo.Find(x => x.PKID == PKID).Result.ShouldBe(ExpectedResultId);
}
```

Comment: you cannot use  the implicit var  with the conditionel operator  if there is  not an implicit conversion between  _ARepo and _BRepo

Comment: Noted that, but its quite easy to asume that the _(x)Repo is of the same `Type` if you just look at the way the code is structured, and that the Connection String would only be different for Server 'A' and Server 'B'
However I have updated my answer to cover if it is the same and if it is not the same

Answer (score 1):

If all Repos implements the same interface (like IRepo). you can create a helper method like this

```
    private IRepo GetRepo(string server)
    {
        var repos = new Dictionary<string, IRepo>
        {
            { "A", _ARepo },
            { "B", _BRepo }
        };

        return repos[server];
    }
```

The use is very simple

```
    private void CheckData(long PKID, int ExpectedResultId, string Server)
    {
        var repo = GetRepo(Server);
        repo.GetAll().Find(x => x.PKID == PKID).Result.ShouldBe(ExpectedResultId);
    }
```